# Best practices for adding SSL and preserving backlinks

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, https, backlinks

If I have many backlinks that points to `http://example.com` and then enforce SSL so that the URL then becomes `https://example.com`, What should I do to ensure that I do not lose these backlinks? One will say: Use 301, that's correct, but, what if I also plan to move from domain x to domain y... An action that will itself include 301's... I guess I should first replace the domain, and only than change the protocol and only then make final redirects.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to move to HTTPS, [the right kind of redirect to use is a 301 redirect](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633), which says you've moved the page permanently to a new spot.

About the use of 301 redirects when moving to a new domain, Google [says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1lVPrYoBkA) the following:

> If you can do those [301] redirects to do the granularity of page level to page level, that's a great user experience. And the PageRank and those sorts of things should flow relatively well to the new site as well.

Google [has said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Filv4pP-1nw) some PageRank is lost on 301 redirects though; I do not know if they make an exception for this case. However, [HTTPS will positively affect your site's ranking](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html), so switching to HTTPS is unlikely to hurt your site's rank.

(Make sure to read Google's [other advice](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6073543) on moving your site to HTTPS as well.)